# Querying Large Datasets in Cassandra

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql

I am by experience a RDBMS programmer. I am working on a scientific research problem involving genomic data. I was assigned to explore Cassandra since we needed a Big Data, scalable and cheap (free) solution. Setting Cassandra up and loading it with data was seductively trivial and similar to my experience with traditional DBs like Oracle and MySQL. My problem is finding a simple strategy to query data since this is a fundamental requirement for all data repositories. The data I am working with is mutation datasets which contain positional information as well as calculated numerical measures regarding the data. I set up an initial static column family that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE variant (
chrom text,
pos int,
ref text,
alt text,
aa text,
ac int,
af float,
afr_af text,
amr_af text,
an int,
asn_af text,
avgpost text,
erate text,
eur_af text,
ldaf text,
mutation_id text,
patient_id int,
rsq text,
snpsource text,
theta text,
vt text,
PRIMARY KEY (chrom, pos, ref, alt)
) WITH
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

CREATE INDEX af_variant_idx ON variant (af);
```

As you can see there is a natural primary key of positional data (chrome, pos, ref and alt). This data is not meaningful from a querying point of view. Much more interesting to my clients currently is to extract data with an 'AF' value below a certain value. I am using Java restful services to interact with this database using the CQL JDBC driver. It quickly became apparent that directly querying this table would not work using AF since it seems like the select statement must identify the row keys that you want to look at. I found some confusing discussions on this point but what I decided to do was since the distinct values of AF are below 100 values, I built a lookup table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE af_lookup (
  af_id float,
  column1 text,
  column2 text,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (af_id, column1, column2)
 ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
 bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
 caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
 comment='' AND
 dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
 gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
 read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
 replicate_on_write='true' AND
 populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
 compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
 compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

This was meant to be a dynamic table with very wide rows. I populated this table based on those data stored on my static column family. The 'AF' value is the key and the compound key from the other table is concantenate by '-' (i.e.1-129-T-G) and stored as a string as a dynamic column name. This worked OK but I still do not understand how all of these things work together. Dynamic Column Families seem to only work as advertised using CQL -2 but I really need to utilize function like >, <, >=, <=. It seems like this is theoretically possible but I have not found a solution in the last 4 weeks of trying a number of different tools (I tried astyanax as well as the JDBC driver).

I have two primary problems, the first is the rpc timeout limitation for querying these data which could produce 10 of thousands to millions of records. The second problem is how to present these data in HTML by getting the data that has not been presented already (previous - next links). Similar to the way opscenter displays column family record data. This doesn't seem possible with the functional limitations of not being able to use >, <, >=, <=. Based on my experience this is probably a lack of understanding on my part of how this product really works rather than a lack of capability of the product (databases wouldn't be very useful if they were only capable of handling writes well).

Is there anyone out there that has encountered this issue and solved it before? I would really appreciate sharing an example of how to implement a C* solution using java web services to display a large number of results that will have to be paginated through.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to explore and use Playorm for Cassandra as it can resolve your problem of timout limitation and pagination. PlayOrm returns a cursor when you query and as your first page reads in the first 20 results and displays it, the next page can just use the same cursor in your session and it picks up right where it left off without rescanning the first 20 rows again.
Visit http://buffalosw.com/wiki/An-example-to-begin-with-PlayOrm/ to see the example for cursor and http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/ for all features and more details about playorm

Comment: Thanks Easility. I downloaded and built Playorm. In trying the simplest example I am getting the the java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException I have imported this jar into my project in eclipse but it is still throwing this runtime error. Do you know why it ca't find this library?

Comment: Got past this and several other missing dependencies. Now I am encountering this error: Failure scanning class(see chained exception)=class com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta. Any thoughts on what this might mean?

Comment: Can you please share the complete error log related to it. Also, make sure that nosql.Persistence.java is in your classpath where you have your Model classes. See the FAQs at http://buffalosw.com/wiki/FAQ/

Comment: Also, the easiest way to start and play around is download source, run ./gradlew eclipse and then import into eclipse and then all the test cases work and you can run them in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Easility. I definitely don't have this java file in my project or my download of PlyORM. Can you tell me where to obtain it?

Comment: No log was attached..I think you need to put that in answer as Comments in SO have limited words limitation

Comment: and nosql.Persistene will be there..Check this https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/tree/master/src/main/java/nosql   if not, try downloading the code again

Comment: I was successful at building PlayORM once I got all the dependencies and the Persistance.java in my classpath. It seems to be running OK now except it can't find any of the tables in my instance of C*. here is the error:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Meta data(or Entity)=af_lookup cannot be found. I can query this table directly in cqlsh or cassandra-cli.  I created all the tables with cqlsh. Could that be why they are not being recognized?

Comment: As an aside, when I ran the code 4 column families were created in the keyspace called DboMetaColumn, DboMetaDatabase, DboMetaTable, StringIndice. This is unexpected behaviour. Can you tell me the purppse of these CFs?

Comment: Dbo*  and *Indcie are Playorm's columnfamilies. This is an expected behavior. These columnfamilies store metadata for all your model entities. For Your IllegalArgumentException, can you please provide the complete stacktrace and if possible the code where you are trying to use that entity.

Comment: Actually, you have to let Playorm create the tables for you so that it can have their meta with it. Do not create a column family from cassandra's Command line interface. Instead rely on Playorm by annotating your Model class with @NoSqlEntity